# pushing into ko.observableArray not updating the UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a 2 view models

```
function group(){
name = "";
description = "";
members = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

and

```
function groupTypes(){
gorupA = ko.observableArray([]);
groupB = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

I have a regular JS array `groupArray` with `group` type objects as elements.

I've separate templates for `groupA-template` and `groupB-template`

I did:

```
var groupTypeInstance = new groupTypes;
groupTypeInstance.groupA.push(groupArray.slice(0,4));
ko.applyBindingsToNode(
            document.getElementById('group-a'),
            {
                template: {
                    name: "groupA-template",
                    foreach: groupTypeInstance.groupA
                }
            }
        );
```

This displayed the UI correctly.
But afterwards when I do `groupTypeInstance.groupA.push(groupArray[5])`, nothing happens. UI doesnt change. Console doesn't show any error. Array has the extra element when I print it in console. Why is the UI not getting updated?

Please ask for more details if needed.

Comment: Please provide cod for a full (but minimal) repro in the question. There's quite a few bits missing to reproduce the issue, and the problem might well lie in those bits. Preferably convert your code samples to a Stack Snippet (on the editor toolbar) to create a runnable repro.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is do not work. You misspelled `groupA` and forgot the `this.` on the variables. Also, you cannot add individual array itens to another array by calling `push()` (it will work but not as you probably intended). Here is the code to do what you want, based on what you posted:

```js
$(function(){

 function group(){
  this.name = "";
  this.description = "";
  this.members = ko.observableArray([]);
 }

 function groupTypes(){      
  this.groupA = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.groupB = ko.observableArray([]);      
 }
  
 var groupArray = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"] ; 
  
 var groupTypeInstance = new groupTypes();
  
  groupTypeInstance.groupA.push.apply(groupTypeInstance.groupA, groupArray.slice(0,4));
  
 ko.applyBindingsToNode(
            document.getElementById('group-a'),
            {
                template: {
                    name: "groupA-template",
                    foreach: groupTypeInstance.groupA
                }
            }
        );
  
  
   setInterval(function(){
     groupTypeInstance.groupA.push(groupArray[5]);
   }, 1000);
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="groupA-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: $data"></h3>    
</script>



<div id="group-a">
  
  
 
</div>
```